# Activerecord sum calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Help me please. I have some table with fields online and offline => when person comes online and offline. If person is still online, offline field is equal NULL and will updates only after person will go offline.

And I need calculate duration of person seanses, but using sql.
I have two scopes:

```
scope :since, lambda { |date| where(["online >= ?", date.to_time.midnight]) }
scope :upto, lambda { |date| where(["online <= ?", date.to_time.end_of_day]) }
```

which helps me to filter person records.
How can I calculate duration correctly after applying needed scopes? (or some other statements).
Is there in activerecord something like IF NULL, and how can I use this if it really exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `sum` function again.

```
Model.where(...condition....).sum("IFNULL(offline, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-online")
```

And I think to a scope you can simply add the sum method I used in this example

Comment: I replace CURRENT_TIMESTAMP by '#{Time.current.utc}' and it works fine. Thank you!